# How to remove Permissions in Android apps made with PhoneGap Build?

Tags: android, web-applications, cordova, web, permissions

I made a WEB app (Android APK) using PhoneGap Build. IT is just a simple 1-page app that have only text and some small graphical attributes in it.  I uploaded it on Play Store. Now when user downloads the app he is asked to allow all possible permissions to the app. I have not found how I control permissions on PhoneGap Build.
My app needs no special permissions and I'd like to exclude them with my next update on Play Store.
How do I solve this Problem?

Answer (score 1):

To keep plugins from re-adding unnecessary permissions edit plugins/android.json.

Please note that this is a "dirty" solution. After adding/updating plugins, you'll probably have to repeat this.

Answer (score 0):

Delete unnecessary uses-permissions from AndroidManifest.xml.
Also it may be useful to delete unnecessary features from res/xml/config.xml.

Answer (score 0):

adding this to your config.xml should clear all permissions:

`<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>`

Comment: I tried with phonegap-cli version 8.1.1 and it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and what assisted me in removing unnecessary permissions was removing this code from my **config.xml**

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />

<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />

<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />

<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
```

and replaced it with

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>

<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"  />

<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information"  />

<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen"  />
```

This allowed my app to have the access internet permission only and removed the others.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in the current version of PhoneGap Build, inside the config.xml file. Note the xmlns entries:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="it.letturedametropolitana.ldmapp" version="0.1.0"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
  xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest" mode="delete">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
  [add any permission you want to delete]
</gap:config-file>
```

To know what to delete and how, you need to open the packaged apk with [apktool](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) and check the AndroidManifest.xml file: copy exactly what you need to delete.

It is all explained in the [docs](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_config_file_element.md.html), although the current version of the docs doesn't use the gap namespace and it doesn't work in my tests.

Answer (score -1):

In this thread in the [Phonegap Community](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/removing_permissions_for_android_app) someone asked about. The dude got the issue solved using an app calleed [ConfiGAP](http://configap.com/) that helps you setting up Android permissions via its interface.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @tomrozb already modified the answer. Tell me if I need to add more details.